# Get a list of files that don't contain something from another list

Tags: c#, linq

Trying to get all the files ending in .XML in a directory that don't contain a keyword.  So the path may be something like "C:\mypath\string1-filename.xml" and it shouldn't be in the list since it contains the key word.

Here is what I have:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles( "C:\\mypath", "*.xml" )
                .Where( f => !f.Contains( "string1" ) && !f.Contains( "string2" ) && !f.Contains( "string3" ) )
                .ToList();
```

I would like to change it to be a little cleaner; something like:

```
var exclusionList = new List<string> { "string1", "string2", "string3"  };
var files = Directory.GetFiles( "C:\\mypath", "*.xml" )
                .Where( f => !f.Contains(exclusionList) )
                .ToList();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var exclusionList = new List<string> { "string1", "string2", "string3" };

        var files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\mypath", "*.xml")
                        .Where(f => !exclusionList.Any(s => f.Contains(s)))
                        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You are not reading the content of file</strike>.Please try following code snippet.
 **Update**
I misunderstood the question.I have updated the answer

```
 var exclusionList = new List<string> { "string1", "string2", "string3"  };
    var files = Directory.GetFiles( "C:\\mypath", "*.xml" )
                    .Where(f => !exclusionList.Any(s => f.Contains(s)))
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: I guess you misunderstood the OP.he doesn't want to check file content, he wants to check file path

Answer (score 1):

There is no extension method to do this directly.So maybe this extension method could help you:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static bool ContainsAny(this string source, ICollection<string> words)
    {
        foreach (var word in words)
        {
            if (source.Contains(word)) return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
var exclusionList = new List<string> { "string1", "string2", "string3"  };
 var files = Directory.GetFiles( "C:\\mypath", "*.xml" )
                      .Where( f => !f.ContainsAny(exclusionList) )
                      .ToList();
```